# Ending a PHP block while in an else if to output HTML which itself contains PHP blocks

Tags: php, html, scope

So, I have the following `else if`:

```
else if (isset($_POST['orderID'])) {
    /* Update order. */
    $orderID = $_POST['orderID'];
    $link = getConn();
    $custInfo = getCustData($orderID, $link, $tableName);
    //$custInfo contains [id, order_id, student, firstname, lastname, email, address, phone, price, size, anchovies,
    //pepperoni, peppers, olives, onions, createdatetime]
    ?>
    <form id='updateOrder' name='orderID' method='post' action='vieworder.php'>
    <h3>What Size of Pizza Would You Like?</h3>
    Small <input id='small' type='radio' name='pizzaSize' value='small' <?php echo ($custInfo[9]=='small')?'checked':''?>/>
    Medium <input id='medium' type='radio' name='pizzaSize' value='medium' <?php echo ($custInfo[9]=='medium')?'checked':''?>/>
    Large <input id='large' type='radio' name='pizzaSize' value='large' <?php echo ($custInfo[9]=='large')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    <h3>Add Extra Toppings</h3>
    Anchovies <input id='anchovies' type='checkbox' name='anchovies' value='yes' <?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    Pineapples <input id='pineapples' type='checkbox' name='pineapples' value='yes'<?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    Pepperoni <input id='pepperoni' type='checkbox' name='pepperoni' value='yes'<?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    Olives <input id='olives' type='checkbox' name='olives' value='yes' <?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    Onions <input id='onions' type='checkbox' name='onions' value='yes' <?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    Peppers <input id='peppers' type='checkbox' name='peppers' value='yes' <?php echo ($custInfo[10]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    <h3>Enter your details:</h3>
    First Name: <input id='forename' type='text' name='forename' value="<?php echo htmlentities($custInfo[3]); ?>" required/>
    <br>
    Surname: <input id='surname' type='text' name='surname' value="<?php echo htmlentities($custInfo[4]); ?>" required/>
    <br>
    Address: <textarea id='address' name='address' rows='5' cols='30' value="<?php echo htmlentities($custInfo[6]); ?>" required></textarea>
    <br>
    Email Address: <input id='email' type='email' name='email' value="<?php echo htmlentities($custInfo[5]); ?>" required/>
    <br>
    Phone Number: <input id='phoneNumber' type='text' name='phone' value="<?php echo htmlentities($custInfo[7]); ?>" required/>
    <br>
    Tick here if you are a student: <input id='studentDiscount' type='checkbox' name='student'<?php echo ($custInfo[2]=='Y')?'checked':''?>/>
    <br>
    <button type='submit' value='Place Order'>Submit Order</button>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

I close the PHP block where the `else if` is began in after getting `$custInfo` and then begin to redisplay a html form that the user had filled in earlier. I use more PHP blocks inside the HTML to fill in the form as it is created with the values stored in `$custInfo`. I then start another PHP block and close the else if and the file continues.

Calling `var_dump($custInfo)` after initialising `$custInfo` gives an expected result:

> array(17) { ["id"]=> string(3) "193" ["order_id"]=> string(13) "5550a328ddb36" ["student"]=> string(1) "Y" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "Peadar" ["lastname"]=> string(11) "Ó Duinnín" ["email"]=> string(15) "email@email.com" ["address"]=> string(32) "Line 1, Line 2, City, County." ["phone"]=> string(10) "0870123456" ["price"]=> string(5) "15.00" ["size"]=> string(5) "large" ["anchovies"]=> string(1) "Y" ["pineapples"]=> string(1) "N" ["pepperoni"]=> string(1) "N" ["peppers"]=> string(1) "Y" ["olives"]=> string(1) "Y" ["onions"]=> string(1) "Y" ["createdatetime"]=> string(19) "2015-05-11 13:40:08" }

However, I get the following output:
[image]

Is this a scope issue or am I doing something else wrong here? I can provide more code or a JSFiddle if requested. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see no value for `$custInfo[10]` in your var_dump. Do you? `$custInfo` has named properties, not numbered.

Comment: @JonathanM I do. It contains `Y`.

Comment: Really? Where? I see that `pineapples` and `pepperoni` and such have values of `Y`, but there is no `10`.

Comment: @JonathanM Yeah, I saw what you meant after I commented. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array `$custInfo` is an associative array the numerical offset won't be available.  Instead of `9` or `10` you need to use the associated key that you assigned to it.